# old JSFiddle not working in new JSFiddle

Tags: jsfiddle

I open this Fiddle: [working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dvtofn6L/1/)

And run it and it works

I create a new jsFiddle under my account and copy the "HMTL", CSS and "Javascript" from this jsFiddle into my newly created fiddle.

I insert the latest jQuery link into External Resources Save and run.

It shows the 2 hyperlinks, but not styled.

I click the Grow link and I get the error message:

```
{"error": "Please use POST request"}
```

So what do I need to do to get anything to work in fiddle

Comment: Did you use the same version of jQuery (`jquery-1.11.1.min.js`)?

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure your version uses the same version of jQuery that this example is using (i.e. *jquery-1.11.1.min.js*):

[image: jquery]

Next, check that your HTML DOCTYPE is HTML 5 and that your Javascript uses AngularJS 1.2.1.

[image: fiddle]